# Simple perl mysql query not working

Tags: mysql, perl

I've been out of the mysql and perl game for quite a few years and can't seem to get this right. I have a table with just 3 columns. 'cnt' is one of them. All I want to do is query the table on 'name' and see if name exists. If it does, I want to capture the value of 'cnt'. The table has a record of testName with a value of 2 I added manually. When this script is run it returns empty.

```
my $count;
my $pop = qq(SELECT cnt FROM popular WHERE name="testName"); 
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($pop); 
$sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr; 

my @return; 

while (@return = $sth->fetchrow_array()) { 
   $count = $return[1]; 
} 

print "our return count is $count";
```

Is it obvious to anyone what I did wrong?

Comment: does "returns empty" mean it doesn't even print out "our return count is"?

Comment: It prints out the string but it stops after "is". $count doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Crossposted at [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1063854).

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean

```
$count = $return[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [perl doc on mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#fetchrow_arrayref,fetchrow_arrayref)

**An alternative to fetchrow_arrayref. Fetches the next row of data and returns it as a list containing the field values**.
    Since you select **cnt** as the return value ,so , the size of @return is 1,but you misunderstand it as the number of results which meets your query condition.No, it is not so!Please have a more careful reading of perl doc.